# Solve $u_t + (x^2)tu_x = 0$ with the initial condition $u_0(x) = \cos(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Could you explain to me [how they solved this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqAnW.png) using the charatheristics method (transport equation)? I don't understand how to derive the charateristics, do I integrate? Do I differentiate? I have no idea.

In [their solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqAnW.png), I don't understand how they derived those fractions (or anything really).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you take a curve $(t,x(t))$ with the property that 
$$
x'(t)=x(t)^2t
$$
Then by the chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x(t))=0
$$
for any $u$ satisfying your pde. In other words, any potential solution will be constant along curves satisfying the ode, so given initial condition for our curve $(0,x(0))=(0,x_0)$, we have, thanks to the initial data given,
$$
u(t,x(t))=\cos(x_0)
$$
This observation suggest a way to build solutions (in fact provably the unique solution, using ode theory of existence and uniqueness).

So, what is $x(t)$? solving the ode via an easy separation of variables, we find 
$$
\frac{1}{x}=\frac{C-t^2}{2}\implies x=\frac{2}{C-t^2}\
\implies x=\frac{2}{\frac{2}{x_0}-t^2}
$$
where we take $x_0$ an arbitrary (nonzero) initial value on the $x$ axis in the $(t,x)$ plane on which $u$ is defined. This is a good choice since we know what our solution ought to be doing at $t=0$, it is just $\cos(x_0)$ by your initial condition. Since again, our solution is constant along these projected characteristics, it will stay $\cos(x_0)$.

Since we don't want to solve uncountably many of these odes (one for each $x_0$), it would be good to solve for 
$x_0$ in terms of $x$ and $t$. This is readily done as 
$$
\frac{2}{x_0}=\frac{2}{x}+t^2\implies x_0=\frac{x}{1+\frac{1}{2}xt^2}
$$
and your solution is 
$$
u(t,x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{1+\frac{1}{2}xt^2} \right)
$$
Where we assumed $x_0\ne 0$ in order to divide. However, if $x_0$ is zero, then we have that the pde is just $1=\cos(0)$ along the characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! How do you get C to be 2/x_0?

Comment: No problem. I solved $x(0)=2/C$, i.e. plugged in $t=0$